# How do I extract a string of text that lies between *>...* using .NET C# regex or anything else?

Tags: c#, string, character, extract, between

I have a string like this.

```
*>-0.0532*>-0.0534*>-0.0534*>-0.0532*>-0.0534*>-0.0534*>-0.0532*>-0.0532*>-0.0534*>-0.0534*>-0.0534*>-0.0532*>-0.0534*
```

I wanna extract between `*>` and `*` characters.

I tried this pattern which is wrong here below:

```
        string pattern = "\\*\\>..\\*";

        Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        MatchCollection matches = rgx.Matches(seriGelen);

        if (matches.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (Match match in matches)
                MessageBox.Show("{0}", match.Value);
        }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You've done well by posting your attempted solution, however, you'll get better answers if you describe what about your solution didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Is there an error at the beginning of the string? Missing an asterisk after first number? >-0.0532>-0.0534*>

If not try this.

```
>([-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+)\*
```

C# Code

```
string strRegex = @">([-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+)\*";
Regex myRegex = new Regex(strRegex, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline);
string strTargetString = @">-0.0532>-0.0534*>-0.0534*>-0.0532*>-0.0534*>-0.0534*>-0.0532*>-0.0532*>-0.0534*>-0.0534*>-0.0534*>-0.0532*>-0.0534*";

foreach (Match myMatch in myRegex.Matches(strTargetString))
{
  if (myMatch.Success)
  {
    // Add your code here
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, there was a copy-paste error. I fixed it. Thanks for your answer. I will try it.

Comment: VS says Unrecognized escape sequence for point \. and last asteriks \*

Comment: I modified it a little bit. Now it is working but it returns with > sign like >-0.532. I can't seperate > sign. @dre
<!-- language: c# -->

>([-+]?[0-9]*.?[0-9]+)*

Comment: The original pasted code is for .NET. No modifications needed. I have updated the answer with the c# code.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there are can be very different values (UPD: there was an integer positive value). So, let me to not check numbers format. Also I will consider that `*>` and `>`, *and also* `*` are just different variants of delimiters.

I'd like to suggest the following solution.

```
 (?<=[>\*])([^>\*]+?)(?=[>\*]+)
```

(http://regex101.com/r/mM7nK1)

Not sure it is ideal. Will only works if your input starts and ends with delimiters, but will allow to you to use *matches* instead *groups*, as your code does.

========

But you know, why wouldn't you use `String.Split` function?

```
var toprint = seriGelen.Split(new [] {'>', '*'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Comment: I wanted to learn regex. But your idea and regex101 site is very helpful. Thanks @mazharenko

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple regex:

```
(?<=\*>).*?(?=\*)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Sample code:

```
string text = "*>-0.0532*>-0.0534*>-0.0534*>-0.0532*>-0.0534*>-0.0534*>-0.0532*>-0.0532*>-0.0534*>-0.0534*>-0.0534*>-0.0532*>-0.0534*";
string[] values = Regex.Matches(text, @"(?<=\*>).*?(?=\*)")
                       .Cast<Match>()
                       .Select(m => m.Value)
                       .ToArray();
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This pattern working correctly.